# Adding custom button to the share intent chooser

Tags: android

Is it possible to add our custom buttons to the share intent chooser.
example

[image]

I have searched around the web and found nothing.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

Comment: they are all based on Intents, more info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: Yes you need to use ShareActionProviders ,

follow this:https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/shareaction.html

Comment: Sorry, maybe your question is not clear enough. "Do you want to create a custom share intent chooser that contains custom buttons within your application?", or "Do you want to include your application to default android system share intent chooser?"

Comment: Tell me first how you design it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your Activity to this list. You should use special intent filter with mime types for this:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

See here for getting more details:
https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to add intent filter in your activity to do your task.

```
<intent-filter
android:label="Share with my app">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Add mime type also, means what you are gonna receive in intent filter:

```
<data android:mimeType="image/*" />
<data android:mimeType="text/*" />
```

But you have to receive data at your activity when other app sent data to your app
[This tutorial will help](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-receiving-data-from-the-send-intent--mobile-14878)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, except you make your custom view that contains the applications for share and your custom buttons. Although you can, that is an anti-pattern in Android. See Roman Nurik's post on Google+ [here](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/6PwgQPMvK1p), item number 4.

**4) Custom non-Android sharing (not using ACTION_SEND)**

Here is the example code of how you can do that

```
private void showCustomView() {
    PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = pm.queryIntentActivities(getShareImageIntent("YOUR_IMAGE_URI"), 0);

    // code for showing your custom view
    // ...
    // do whatever you want with your custom buttons
    // end code for showing your custom view

    // BELOW IS HOW YOU COULD LAUNCH THE SPECIFIC APPLICATION WHEN ONE OF THE APPLICATION ITEMS CLICKED
    // from ResolveInfo you can get ActivityInfo
    ActivityInfo activityInfo = resolveInfo.activityInfo;
    // then you can create ComponentName
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, activityInfo.name);
    // launch the application you want to share
    Intent intent = getShareImageIntent("YOUR_IMAGE_URI");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    intent.setComponent(componentName);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

/**
 * Example method to get share intent for applications that receive image Uri
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private Intent getShareImageIntent(Uri imageUri) {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    else
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);

    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    return shareIntent;
}
```